# How can i add static data to Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I used core date in my app. I searched core data functions.I learned add and get data from core data. But i wanna add my data staticly.So i wanna add data to core data(not in code they ar  default datas) and use them in app delegate.But i couldn't add data manually. So is there anybody that can help me?  Thanks.

Comment: The purpose of Core Data is object persistence, not general data storage.  It optionally uses a database but it doesn't really serve the same function as a database.

Comment: i know that. In my project i used more core data functions.But i need add default values in it for starting of project.and i must do that in core data.

Comment: You don't HAVE to do that in CoreData (unless this is some kind of development criteria or specified in some kind of contract).  A PList will work just fine for what you are wanting to do.  Another observation - you asked for help and are getting it.  When someone with more experience than you is trying to give you insight into a better way of doing things, the prudent person takes the advice.

Comment: @yatanadam, any luck in the last month?

Answer (score 0):

You could always check for the existance of objects in a `CoreData` entity and if empty, add objects to that entity (this would prevent duplication).  That being said, if you are talking about having static data in your app, why not use a `PList`?  `CoreData` is really overkill for that kind of scenario.

BTW - If you haven't used [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) (a CoreData helper class), you should check it out.  It makes working with CD much easier IMO.

Comment: i use core data in my project. (after user logged in). its usefulll for me.but i wanna save deafult values in it for start.And this method isnt so good i think. Do you know better one?

Comment: Just because you use CD in your project doesn't mean it has to be used to store everything.  Like I said, in the scenario you are describing, using a PList or NSUserDefaults (if this is a small amount of data) is going to be better than using the equivalent of an automated warehouse to store a single savings bond.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData itself provides no way to pre-package, as it were, any data ahead of time for delivery with the app. You must package it in another format, ship the app, and then copy it all into core data at your first startup.

For example, you might, on your development computer, create a `.plist` file, read it into an `NSDictionary`, and then populate your CoreData store. Or you could do the same with a home-grown SQLite store, if you would benefit from all that extra structure. If you really wanted to be brave, you could even pull the data from a web service. The sky is the limit!

Finally, you might consider submitting a feature request to Apple. In cases like this, your request acts as a signature on a petition, adding to the thousands of other developers who have yearned for similar functionality over the years.

Comment: thanks for asnwer psoft. what about sqlite? can i save these datas tehere ?

Comment: Just like CoreData, sqlite to store static values is not a good use case.

Comment: @yatanadam: yes - it's there in my answer. Just create the sqlite file and package with your app. Read the Resources Programming Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i